# past tense vs present perfect vs past perfect

Tags: present-perfect, past-perfect, past-simple, past-vs-present-perfect

These are the words spoken by a cinema hero, about fight sequences in a newspaper interview

> But I **have done** riskier action scenes in my prime.

---

Why "have done (present perfect format)" is used here? Can we use past tense or past perfect formats as given below? If so, what is the difference in meaning in these three forms?

> But I **had done** riskier action scenes in  my prime
>
> But I **did** riskier action scenes in my prime

Comment: _Had done_ would only make sense if the action is one stage further back in the past. "Yesterday, I told the interviewer that I had done riskier action scenes in my prime."

Comment: @KateBunting So both "Have done" and "did" are acceptable? If so, is there any difference in meaning or context?

Comment: Well, I suppose "I did" suggests that he is thinking of 'his prime' as being long past, and "I have done" that he is thinking of the action scenes as part of his lifetime's achievements. I hope this makes sense.